# compare java fx date picker date to sql date inside a query

Tags: java, mysql, date, javafx, javafx-datepicker

I want to know how I can compare a mysql date to a java fx date picker date. So if I have a datepicker date in MM/DD/YYYY format and a mysql date in YYYY/MM/DD format how do I compare those two inside a query?

Comment: Just format it according to the date column in the query.

Comment: How do I format it in javafx? I know for java.util.date you can format it with simpledateformat, but how do I do it for javafx?

Comment: But You can still use java.util.date here is no different.

Comment: I tried, but it says I cannot convert java.util.date to java fx date picker.

Comment: Show your code it will be easy to help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prepared for you small appliaction how to convert `Date` to `LocalDate` and set in `DatePicker`, how to take `LocalDate` from `DatePicker` and convert to `Date`. You can also check that date are the same.

```
public class Main extends Application {

  SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
  private Date dateUtil = sdf.parse("2016/09/25");

  public Main() throws ParseException {
  }

  @Override public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    Button button = new Button("Take date from DatePicker");
    Label labelCompare = new Label();
    Label labelCompare2 = new Label();
    DatePicker datePicker = new DatePicker();

    //convert Date to LocalDate
    LocalDate localDate = dateUtil.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate();
    //set in DatePicker
    datePicker.setValue(localDate);

    VBox hBox = new VBox();
    hBox.getChildren().addAll(datePicker, button, labelCompare, labelCompare2);
    Scene scene = new Scene(hBox, 400, 400);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();

    button.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
      @Override public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
        //Take LocalDate from DatePicker
        LocalDate localDate = datePicker.getValue();

        //Convert LocalDate to Date
        Date dateFromPicker = Date.from(localDate.atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant());

        //compare
        labelCompare.setText("Compare date: " + dateUtil.compareTo(dateFromPicker));
      }
    });
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch();
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks, I just found out that .getValue().toString() returns the datepicker value in same format as sql. But I will need your answer for later conversions.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way:
String searched_date = datePicker.getValue().toString();
Date dateFromPicker = Date.valueOf(searched_date);

Comment: Welcome to stack! In your answers, try to be more in-depth about your code :)

Comment: @mirunna1 this answer doesn't answer the OP.  `Timestamp.valueOf(dataPicker.getValue().atStartOfDay())` would give a value that can be used in SQL - albeit in local time.. The OP wasn't specific about TZ impact - but it is something to be considered when dealing with UI values VS server values.  If you have more information please add it to the answer.